# How to use pROC to plot a roc when having got TPR and FPR?

Tags: r

I have got TPR and FPR as follows. I want to know whether I can use pROC or ROCR to plot a roc. I cannot provide label and score to the function roc.
TPR=c(0,0,0.5,1,1) FPR = c(0,0.12,0.23,0.37,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `plot` or `ggplot` if you have TPR and FPR:

```
plot(FPR, TPR, lwd = 2, col = "blue", type = "b", las = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to produce a beautiful figure and last use ggplot2 to finish it.